# Encoding/charset issues on apache httpclient5 multipart request (kotlin)

Tags: java, kotlin, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters, apache-httpclient-5.x

I am switching my HTTP rest client from ktor to apache httpclient 5.1.3. So, I have to make some changes to adapt my code to work. And the MultipartEntity is not working for me as expected, because when I put a byte array from a Base64 string, apparently there are some parsing issues with some characters, particularly the ["DEL" character](https://bytetool.web.app/en/ascii/code/0x7f/), which in the ktor console output does not appear visible but in the httpclient output appears as [0x7f].

This is a comparison between the console log lines, with ktor on the left and httpclient on the right

[image]

So, the payloads are different, I checked if any charset was not being matched but none of that seems to be the problem. Also, I don't know if there is any relation to ktor being a kotlin library while httpclient is a java one.

When copying the first line into vscode or another editor, one can see there is a character before the '5' character that is not visible here. In the second line, said character appears as [0x7f]

> [0xffffffc5]5[0x1d]

> [0xffffffc5][0x7f]5[0x1d]

The response I am getting is a 200 OK, but the response body is not the right one. The problem comes from trying to validate a "baked image", which contains data embedded in it, in https://badgecheck.io. If I send a multipart request with an image from Postman I get the correct data but if sent from my app through httpclient I get this error:

> {
> "graph": [],
> "input": {
> "value": null
> },
> "report": {
> "messages": [
> {
> "name": "DETECT_INPUT_TYPE",
> "success": false,
> "result": "<class 'TypeError'> ['TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object\n']",
> "messageLevel": "ERROR"
> }
> ],
> "errorCount": 1,
> "warningCount": 0,
> "valid": false
> }
> }

This is how I build the multipart request:

```
inline fun <reified T> executeFormMultipartPost(
    url: String,
    bodyForm: ArrayList<NameValuePair>,
    headers: Map<String, MutableList<String>> = mapOf()
): T {
    val httpPost = HttpPost(url)
    for (header in headers) {
        header.value.forEach {
                value -> httpPost.addHeader(header.key, value)
        }
    }
    httpPost.addHeader("Accept-Charset", Charsets.UTF_8)

    var nvParams: ArrayList<NameValuePair> = ArrayList<NameValuePair>()
    for (n in bodyForm){
        nvParams.add(n)
    }

    var builder: MultipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().setContentType(ContentType.create(
        "multipart/form-data"))
    builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.EXTENDED)
    builder.setMimeSubtype("form-data")
    val contentDisposition = nvParams[0].value
    val bytes = BaseEncoding.base64().decode(nvParams[1].value);

    val image = ByteArrayBody(bytes, ContentType.create(
        "multipart/form-data"),"badgeimage")
    val data = StringBody(nvParams[2].value, ContentType.create(
        "multipart/form-data"))
    builder.addPart(nvParams[1].name, image)
    builder.addPart(nvParams[2].name, data)

    val httpEntity = builder.build()
    httpPost.entity = httpEntity

    val response = client.execute(httpPost)
    return returnResponse(url, response)
}
```

So, what could I do to address this? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the "Content-Type" header is unsafe, and it was being overwritten, thus corrupting the request. Had to avoid setting that header in the request object and it worked fine.